# Is Apache Spark streams join possible without HDFS or RocksDB working?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, spark-structured-streaming

In Apache Spark I do join operation between rate stream and csv file reading streaming operation, both of them are needed for very low intensity data generation. Rate produces increasing ids and limits the generation speed, while the csv reader tends to load all the data without rate limit. So jointing the stream should help with limiting the csv data.

```
readFromCSVFile(tmpPath.toString).as("csv").join(rate.as("counter")).where("csv.id == counter.value")
```

Unfortunately, join uses HDFS under the hood, so I'm getting the large error stack:

```
2021-10-15 14:18:02 ERROR Inbox:94 - Ignoring error
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner@137b9386 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4cd6112[Shutting down, pool size = 7, active threads = 7, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 30]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:825)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1355)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.launchTask(Executor.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.$anonfun$reviveOffers$1(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.$anonfun$reviveOffers$1$adapted(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.reviveOffers(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2021-10-15 14:18:02 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec:73 - Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@2d76d5c5 is aborting.
2021-10-15 14:18:02 ERROR WriteToDataSourceV2Exec:73 - Data source write support org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@2d76d5c5 aborted.
2021-10-15 14:18:02 ERROR MicroBatchExecution:94 - Query kafkaDataGenerator [id = 23a9869d-913f-4cf6-b0ed-e8149ed149e6, runId = d98459c0-ae1f-44e8-a610-7ee413740880] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3627)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collect$1(Dataset.scala:2940)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2940)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$15(MicroBatchExecution.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:570)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:223)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 0 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1(DAGScheduler.scala:979)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:977)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:2257)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2170)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:1973)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1357)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1973)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$35(SparkContext.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1932)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:382)
    ... 37 more
2021-10-15 14:18:03 ERROR Utils:94 - Aborting task
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$7(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:445)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:477)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2021-10-15 14:18:03 ERROR DataWritingSparkTask:73 - Aborting commit for partition 30 (task 31, attempt 0, stage 2.0)
```

and the most important part is there:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error committing version 1 into HDFSStateStore[id=(op=0,part=33),dir=file:/C:/Users/eljah32/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-cb8ca918-43cc-43d6-8f36-3bf80d1e7852/kafkaDataGenerator/state/0/33/left-keyWithIndexToValue]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$HDFSBackedStateStore.commit(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:139)
```

It means, that the join operation requires the HDFS to be used. `HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider` is the only possible implementation, another one known is based on RocksDB. I Haven't found a way is it possible to disable `StateStoreProvider` for the join operation, if the data amount is too small and we can rely on memory operatons for the particular job? May be there is some option to disable `StateStoreProvider` usage since there is no pure in memory implementation?

Comment: `file://` URI is a Hadoop compatible filesystem; you don't need "HDFS"

Comment: I supposed the same, but it was required surprisingly when I was using join. Before joining the streams that StateStoreProvider wasn't required under the hood. Also I don't use checkpoints explicitly to use hdfs, just join

Comment: According to your stacktrace, you have a Nullpointerexception within a function at `WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:445`. Has probably nothing to do with hdfs or statestores, other than you obviously can't store null keys for data or join on them